# How to implement Fork-join with rabbitMQ

Tags: php, asynchronous, design-patterns, rabbitmq

I want to implement the [fork-join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork%E2%80%93join_model) pattern in php using rabbitMQ. I managed to split the work to parts and proccess them in parallel. But I don't know how to join the results.

It seems that rabbitMQ has no futures or promisses equivalent.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

this isn't something that RabbitMQ will do for you. You'll have to write your own code to manage it.

The gist of it would be to use a "correlation id" in your messages to get work done. When a response is sent, include the same correlation id.

The code that receives the response will store the response with the correlation id, so that it can put all the responses together when they are all returned.

see the "Splitter" (http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/Sequencer.html)

and "Aggregator" (http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/Aggregator.html)

patterns for more information